# Oracle APEX - I need help to setup dynamic search filter on IG report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an IG region where I disabled the toolbar and created my custom search item.

I want user to be able to type the first three characters of a name on the search item (named P8_SEARCH) and the IG report will only show the name(s) that starts with those 3 characters.

This should happen without clicking any button. The IG report query is shown below:

```
select member_id, first_name, last_name , address, dob, home_phone, cell_phone,
email_address from member_profile where first_name like '%'||:P8_SEARCH||'%';
```

I also created dynamic action with key release event and True action Execute JavaScript Code shown below:

```
var keyPressCount=0;

$("#P8_SEARCH").on("keypress", () => {
    if (keyPressCount < 2) {
        keyPressCount++;
    } else {
        $s("P8_SEARCH", apex.item( "P8_SEARCH" ).getValue());
    }
})
```

How can I achieve this without submitting the page? I will appreciate any suggestion. Example: [image: SCREENSHOT OF IG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an static_id for your IG region, in the dynamic action add `apex.region("yourStaticId").refresh();`to your JS code, this will refresh only the region.
 something like this:

```
var keyPressCount=0;

$("#P8_SEARCH").on("keypress", () => {
    if (keyPressCount < 2) {
        keyPressCount++;
    } else {
        $s("P8_SEARCH", apex.item( "P8_SEARCH" ).getValue());
        apex.region("yourStaticId").refresh();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I added the refresh line to the JS code but I received error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh' of null"   I guess there is a problem with setting the session value of the P8_SEARCH item. Trying to look into that.

Comment: don't forget to set your static_id in the IG region, in my example you have to set the static_id as  yourStaticId

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that worked. I was using "#P8_SEARCH" earlier, instead of "P8_SEARCH"

Answer (score 0):

If the search items are stored in an associated table, my idea is that you could associate a PL/SQL expression to execute using a Process. This process could be executed on a custom action.

Another idea is that you associate the dynamic action with a hidden button press, and make the JavaScript code click on the button. Then, you can 'simulate' the existence of a trigger for your dynamic action with key release event

What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try the approach of pressing an hidden button...